# Concatenate date(timestamp) and hour(numeric) column in one column in psql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a server where tx_date is in timestamp and hour is in numeric are different columns, therefore i need to combine both those columns to get one result in sql query.

these are the columns of my table.

```
tx_date            |hour|customer_obj_num|subscriber_obj_num|
-------------------|----|----------------|------------------|
2019-06-06 00:00:0 |9   |1260340723780   |1260341599747     |
2019-07-12 00:00:0 |9   |1260340917755   |1260341740838     |
2019-07-10 00:00:0 |18  |1261891161687   |1261891162660     |
2019-06-07 00:00:0 |14  |1260341590405   |1260488404515     |
2019-06-27 00:00:0 |10  |1263742570630   |1263742571046     |
```

Need results like this:

```
tx_date              |customer_obj_num|subscriber_obj_num|
---------------------|----------------|------------------|
2019-06-06 09:00:0   |1260340723780   |1260341599747     |
2019-07-12 09:00:0   |1260340917755   |1260341740838     |
2019-07-10 18:00:0   |1261891161687   |1261891162660     |
2019-06-07 14:00:0   |1260341590405   |1260488404515     |
2019-06-27 10:00:0   |1263742570630   |1263742571046     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the hours to an interval using [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.22.1.1) and add that to the timestamp:

If `hour` is not an integer, you need to cast it.

```
select t.tx_date + make_interval(hours => t.hour::int)
from the_table t;
```

If `hour` is a numeric value with decimals (and those decimals) should be honored as fractional hours, you can convert to seconds.

```
select t.tx_date + make_interval(secs => t.hour * 60 * 60)
from the_table t;
```

(and if `hour` doesn't contain fractional hours, then why is it a numeric, and not an integer)

Online example: https://rextester.com/RHYA54311

Comment: getting an error
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function make_interval(hours => numeric) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 19
  ERROR: function make_interval(hours => numeric) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: oh might be the case

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.7

Comment: @BaljotSingh: ah, I overlooked the mentioning of `numeric` in the error message. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

You could cast tx_date as date and just add the hours to it

```
Select tx_date::date + interval '1 hour'*hour from table
```

Comment: great it worked, will test more before giving a thumps up .